# How can I map object if there is duplicated value?

Tags: arrays, loops, elixir

I have two list,`list_a = [%{id: 1, name: "Jack"}, %{id: 2, name: "John}]` and `list_b = [%{id: nil, name: "Jack"}]`

What I want to achieve is that by comparing two lists, if there is duplicated name, add field `status: true`, if not, add field `status: false`.

So expected outcome is `combined_list = [%{id: 1, name: "Jack", status: true}, %{id: 2, name: "John, status: false}]`

In order to achieve the goal, I loop two lists and combine results.

```
list_status_true =
for object <- list_a do
  found =      
    Enum.find(
      list_b,
        fn(x) ->
          x.name == object.name 
        end
      )

  if !is_nil(found) do
    %{
      id: object.id,
      name: object.name,
      status: true
    }
  end 
end

list_status_false =
for object <- list_b do
  found =      
    Enum.find(
      list_a,
        fn(x) ->
          x.name == object.name 
        end
      )

  if is_nil(found) do
    %{
      id: object.id,
      name: object.name,
      status: false
    }
  end 
end

list_status_true ++ list_status_false
```

But I think this function can be simplified.. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd collect all names into a `MapSet` and then loop through `list_b` once, checking if the name exists in the `MapSet`:

```
list_a = [%{id: 1, name: "Jack"}, %{id: 2, name: "John"}]
list_b = [%{id: nil, name: "Jack"}]

names = for x <- list_b, into: MapSet.new, do: x.name

IO.inspect for x <- list_a, do: Map.put(x, :status, x.name in names)
```

Output:

```
[%{id: 1, name: "Jack", status: true}, %{id: 2, name: "John", status: false}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The nearly same solution as provided by @Dogbert, but without comprehensions:

```rb
list_a = [%{id: 1, name: "Jack"}, %{id: 2, name: "John"}]
list_b = [%{id: nil, name: "Jack"}]

names = list_b |> Enum.map(& &1.name) |> Enum.uniq
Enum.map(list_a, fn %{name: name} = e ->
  Map.put(e, :status, name in names)
end)
#⇒ [%{id: 1, name: "Jack", status: true},
#   %{id: 2, name: "John", status: false}]
```